# Replace all the backslash '\' with frontslash '/' during Data Cleansing activity in Python before importing the data in MySQL

Tags: python, pandas, backslash

I have a DataFrame of type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, imported from CSV file which has a column with links having elements as shown below

| sno | link |
| --- | --- |
| A | C:\Users\Documents\SQL\Python Codes\ |
| B | D:/Users/Documents\Pendrive\Example/ |
| C | D:/Users\Documents/Pendrive/Example\ |
| D | D:/Users\Documents/Pendrive/Example |

I am trying to export this data in CSV and load in MySQL.

There's a mix of front and back slash in my links.
Currently the rows with backslash - '\' present at the end, i.e., Row 'A' and 'C' are creating issue while importing in SQL. Row 'B' and 'D' has no problem.

I am performing my pre-process in Python where I am trying to eradicate this error.

How can I replace all the '\' with '/' in my entire DataFrame.

Comment: So you want to preserve the *invalid* paths instead of fixing the bug that prevents importing the *valid* paths? That's not a good idea

Comment: `Row 'A' and 'C' are creating issue while importing in SQL` **why**? That's the bug, not the slash. Are you using string concatenation to generate INSERT statements instead of parameterized queries? This leaves you wide open to SQL injection and conversion problems, like the one you encountered. What happens if one of the lines contains `'); drop table users; --` ? Or `34.567,00` ?

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1: Using [`df.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

You can use the `df.applymap` method with a lambda replace function.

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace("\\", "/"))
```

### Method 2: Using [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

You can also use `df.replace` with regular expression.

```py
df = df.replace(r"\\", "/", regex=True)
```

Comment: This, and the OP's request, produces *bad* paths. The problem isn't the path and won't be fixed by replacements - or rather, paths B, C and D are all wrong and need the *reverse* replacement, but the real problem isn't the paths

Answer (score 1):

I created a dictionary to avoid the unicode error for certain cases, and then finally apply lambda function.

Output in Column 'link1'

```
import pandas as pd

newdf = pd.DataFrame([
    ["A","C:\\Users\\Documents\\SQL\\Python Codes\\"],
    ["B","D:/Users/Documents\\Pendrive\\Example/"],
    ["C","D:/Users\\Documents/Pendrive/Example\\"],
    ["D","D:/Users\\Documents/Pendrive/Example"]],
    columns=['sno','link'])

newdf
```

|  | sno | link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | C:\Users\Documents\SQL\Python Codes\ |
| 1 | B | D:/Users/Documents\Pendrive\Example/ |
| 2 | C | D:/Users\Documents/Pendrive/Example\ |
| 3 | D | D:/Users\Documents/Pendrive/Example |

```
comp_dict = dict()

comp_dict['\x07'] = '\\a'
comp_dict['\x08'] = '\\b'
comp_dict['\x0c'] = '\\f'
comp_dict['\x0b'] = '\\v'

def check_replace(str_data,find,replace,comp_dict):
    for k,v in zip(comp_dict.keys(),comp_dict.values()):
        str_data = str_data.replace(k,v)
    print(str_data)
    return str_data.replace(find,replace)


link = newdf['link']

newdf['link1']= link.map(lambda x: check_replace(x,"\\","/",comp_dict))

newdf
```

|  | sno | link | link1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | C:\Users\Documents\SQL\Python Codes\ | C:/Users/Documents/SQL/PythonCodes/ |
| 1 | B | D:/Users/Documents\Pendrive\Example/ | D:/Users/Documents/Pendrive/Example/ |
| 2 | C | D:/Users\Documents/Pendrive/Example\ | D:/Users/Documents/Pendrive/Example/ |
| 3 | D | D:/Users\Documents/Pendrive/Example | D:/Users/Documents/Pendrive/Example |